# Chemical equilibria - Lab practical

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

In an experiment to determine the partition coefficient, how would we
assure that the system has reached partition equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of chemical equilibrium. The chemical composition becomes "static" when equilibrium is reached i.e., it appears that neither the concentration of the reactants or the products is changing. At a microscopic level the system is dynamic. Apply the same idea to the partition of a substance in phase "A" and "B".

For research purposes, one would analyze liquids (A & B) for the extracted compound as a function of time and note the time when concentration in the two phases becomes constant. This can be easily done by plotting a graph of concentration of the extracted compound in liquid A and B. When both become constant, you have achieved distribution equilibrium.

Now this is not possible in an academic experiment with a limited time. Your teacher may tell you to shake the two liquids in a separatory funnel for a certain time. This implies someone had already done this experiment by the above method and they know that equilibrium is established within 2 mins or 5 min.